# Center a relatively positioned element with unknown width in Firefox

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a block-level element of unknown width.  This element needs to be horizontally centered on the page, and its `position` needs to be `relative` so that its absolutely positioned child will show up in the right place.  You can [see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/mlms13/vhUGL/).

As far as I know, the best way to center an element of unknown width is to set its `display` to `table`. Semantically, this seems incorrect, because my element has nothing in common with a real table.  Even worse, [Firefox doesn't apply position to tables](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35168), so the absolutely positioned child shows up in the wrong spot:

[image]

Are there any workarounds for this that:

- don't add any extra elements to the html
- don't calculate and set the element's width with JavaScript

I'd like a pure CSS fix, and I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: Semantically, setting display properties to `table` is fine. You're not changing the element itself, only its appearance. But I take your point about Firefox, and it has me stumped... for now. How is the width of the div determined?

Comment: @Kalessin: The width of the div is automatically set to the width of the content of its children when you use `display: table` (as it would be with a normal html table).  However, `display: table` elements generally have `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` children, which is why I was worried that `display: table` wasn't very fitting in my case.

Comment: Yes, you would have required extra HTML elements to get that to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `display: inline-block;` to the element (`#box`) should suffice. This will cause it to become an inline element and still keep its "boxy" properties. Its width will automatically take up the width of its children.

Then you can set its alignment by setting `text-align: center;` on its parent.

IE7 does not support this `display` value (only on naturally inline elements), but the situation is the same with `table` (no support at all). [You can use a hack though to make `inline-block` work in IE7.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-does-not-understand-display-inline-block/6545033#6545033)

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vhUGL/3/)

Comment: This is a nice solution but the catch here is that is requires height of the box to be defined.

Comment: @Aziz The height *is* defined, it's the width that's variable.

Comment: @Aziz In his example, he used a fixed height.

Comment: Yes, thats what I was trying to point at. Either height or width has to be defined in this solution. But overall good solution.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, thanks, that works! I had been under the mistaken impression that `inline-block` elements shouldn't contain block-level elements, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Don't worry, I never had any intention of supporting IE 6/7. The ultimate goal is a small JavaScript game that I'm writing for fun -- if it works in any version of IE, we'll call it a miracle.

Comment: @Aziz, why would height or width have to be set with this solution? This seems to work as expected, even without height/width: http://jsfiddle.net/mlms13/vhUGL/7/

Comment: @Michael, sorry my bad. I overlooked bottom: 16px for the child div. Thanks for the fiddle to show that the solution works even without width/height.

Comment: FYI, if you want `display: inline-block` to work in IE7, see this: http://flipc.blogspot.com/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html

Answer (score 1):

If worst comes to worst, you could try `text-align: -moz-center;` which is a Firefox-specific method of centering block elements like inline-elements.