# IE7 does not understand display: inline-block

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, css

Can someone please help me get my head around this bug? With Firefox its working fine but with Internet Explorer 7 its not. It seems not to understand the `display: inline-block;`.

**html:**

```
<div class="frame-header">
    <h2>...</h2>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.frame-header {
    height:25px;
    display:inline-block;   
}
```

Comment: What exactly to you to achieve? What effect?

Answer (score 302, accepted):

The IE7 `display: inline-block;` hack is as follows:

```css
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom: 1;
```

By default, IE7 only supports `inline-block` on naturally `inline` elements ([Quirksmode Compatibility Table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)), so you only need this hack for other elements.

`zoom: 1` is there to trigger [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) behaviour, and we use the [star property hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack) for setting the `display` to `inline` only in IE7 and lower (newer browsers won't apply that). `hasLayout` and `inline` together will basically trigger `inline-block` behaviour in IE7, so we are happy.

This CSS will not validate, and can make your stylesheet messed up anyways, so using an IE7-only stylesheet through [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) could be a good idea.

```
<!–-[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie7.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]–->
```

Comment: I prefer `*zoom:1;` to triger hasLayout. So it's more clearly that the  `*zoom` and `*display` go together

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp the official W3c has not mentioned anything about ie7 - inline block

Comment: @RoshanWijesena w3schools has nothing to do with w3c and neither are authorities on ie7

Comment: @RoshanWijesena w3schools is not a good resource and is not official at all. Do not depend on it. The fact that they mention or do not mention something does not really mean anything.

Comment: thanks Guys! so what should i used as a official documentation just wondering!

Comment: @RoshanWijesena You can find the offical standard specifications on http://w3.org, the official page of W3C. https://developer.mozilla.org is a great resource that you can use instead of w3schools as a reference.

Comment: @HerrSerker I put both rules on the same line with a comment.

Answer (score 8):

### Update

As nobody uses IE6 and 7 anymore I will present a different solution:
***You don't need a hack anymore, because IE8 [supports it by itself](http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block)***

For those who must support those stone age browsers before IE8 (It's not that the IE8 is that old, too *cough*):
For the account of IE version control, use some Conditional Class in `<html>`tag like [Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/) states in [his article](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/)

```
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
```

By this you will have different classes in html-tag for different IE Browsers

The CSS you need is as follows

```
.inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
}
.lt-ie8 .inline-block {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

This will validate and you don't need an extra CSS file

---

### Old answer

```
.frame-header
{
    background:url(images/tab-green.png) repeat-x left top;
    height:25px;
    display:-moz-inline-box;    /* FF2 */
    display:inline-block;   /* will also trigger hasLayout for IE6+7*/
}
/* Hack for IE6 */
* html .frame-header {
    display: inline; /* Elements with hasLayout and display:inline behave like inline-block */
}
/* Hack for IE7 */
* + html .frame-header {
    display: inline; /* Elements with hasLayout and display:inline behave like inline-block */
}
```

Comment: The CSS you show above makes sense but how exactly would that work into the HTML? Thanks.

Comment: @StephenESC two ways. Add the class `inline-block` to the `frame-header` element. Or change `inline-block` by `frame-header` in the CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 does not support 'inline-block' properly, more info here: **[LINK](http://flipc.blogspot.com/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html)**

Use can use: 'inline' instead.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Make us an example and put here: **http://jsfiddle.net/**

Answer (score 0):

use inline, it works with this kind of selectors for list items:

```
ul li {}
```

or to be specific:

```
ul[className or name of ID] li[className or name of ID] {}
```

Comment: `inline` is not the same as `inline-block`. For example, the `height: 25px;` in the example will not take effect when the element is `inline`. Also, the question says nothing about lists.