# Place button above table aligned to the right of the table

Tags: html, css, layout

How can I position a button above a table aligned to the right?

Imagine an imaginary vertical line that is placed to the right of the table. I want right limit of the button to be placed where that line is. Here's a draft:

[image: The example ilustrated]

As you can see, the button is aliged with the table and does not belong to the table.
 The table has its sizes set to auto.
 I already tried using a div as a wrapper but that didn't work. Any alternatives?

Add: I forgot: The table is supposed to be aligned to the left.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add a `div` wrapper around the two with the following CSS:

```
display: inline-block; 
text-align: right;
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GxS5L/1/)

- My solution assumes that the button is not `block`, in that case you also have to float it (`text-align` will not affect it then).
- `display: inline-block;` will not work on IE7, but [there is a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-problem-with-display-inline-block/6545033#6545033).

**Little explanation:**

`display: inline-block;` is the heart of this solution. It makes the container take up the width of its children, in this case probably the `table` (but there is no problem if the button is bigger).

Comment: I don't want the table aligned to the right... (sorry I forgot to mention that)

Comment: @brunoais The table is not aligned anywhere. `text-align` does not affect the table. Check the demo.

Comment: ok, got it. That's what I needed. And now it not only works with my browser, it also works with IE. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about another table that holds the two elements (button and table) and then right-align the top cell? Maybe a little messy, but it would work.

Comment: too much mess. I want absolutely no mess at all. I'll use that only if there is no alternative to that.

Comment: @paperbd -1 for using tables for layout.