# Need center align of ul whose <li> are float left

Tags: html, css, css-float

```
   <style>
   body{
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
      }
    #module_footerLink li{
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
        margin:0 5px;
    }
    .clear{
        clear:both;
    }
    .wrap{
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        width:900px;
            text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <ul id="module_footerLink">
      <li><a id="id_home" href="home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a id="id_the_resort" href="article-AboutUs"><span>The Resort</span></a> </li>
      <li><a id="id_facilities" href="article-facilities"><span>Facilities</span></a></li>
      <li><a id="id_tariff" href="article-tariff"><span>Tariff</span></a></li>
      <li><a id="id_media" href="article-media"><span>Media</span></a></li>
      <li><a id="id_links" href="article-links"><span>Links</span></a></li>
      <li><a id="id_contact_us" href="contact"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
       <li class="clear"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here I want li's in middle of div whose class is wrap. Do any one know how can i do that? I have tried center align but it does not work...............

Comment: do you want that li should move to center of the div , are you trying to make a vertical menu

Comment: no its horizontal menu... all the li must be central align of div with class wrap

Comment: If its a horizontal menu , then you want that all li elements should be next to each other from the left is it, iddnt understand properly what do you mean by center aligned

Comment: just copy paste my above codes in html file then you will know clearly what i really want to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the updated css :-

```
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


#module_footerLink {
margin:auto;
width:450px;
}

#module_footerLink li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 5px;
background:red;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}

.wrap {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 900px;
text-align: center;
background:blue;
}

</style>
```

i think you looking like this:- 
http://jsfiddle.net/eHyuZ/2/

**UPDATED**

Now you can add li's as per your requirement...it will not go anywhere actually your bit of your method was not correct that's why you were facing problems now i have made some changes and made it the navigation in proper way

see the updated link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/eHyuZ/7/

Comment: if i add more li's? It will go down... these li will be dynamically placed later

Comment: you don't need to use the floats in your li because it will come randomly through display:inline; in li....and now you can add more li's in your UL list with div class wrap...

Comment: i have just figure out the problem and saw ur answer thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
      }
    #module_footerLink li{
    display: inline-block;
        list-style:none;
        margin:0 5px;
        /* For IE 7 */
        zoom: 1;
        *display: inline;
    }
    .clear{
        clear:both;
    }
    .wrap{
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        width:900px;
            text-align:center;
    }​
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use margin:0 auto;

```
.wrap{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: you must set width for ul and set margin:0 auto for ul, this work when the number of li's and th total width is fixed otherwise you must use script to calculate the li's width then set to ul.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED by [comment](http://%5Bhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042562/#comment-12847782%5D)

Try add

```
#module_footerLink {
display:inline-block;
/*IE7*/
zoom:1;
*display:inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DEmTh/1/

But in IE7 its not working

Comment: If you need to support IE7 I would use a <table>

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/6545033/1102223
#module_footerLink {
display:inline-block;
*display:inline;
zoom:1;
}