# Navigation bar center position

Tags: css, layout

I am currently working with a bottom navigation bar for a test site. The problem is that the navigation bar does not center properly. I have added the `.left` attribute to keep each block list beside each other. How can I get this bottom navigation bar to center automatically(no matter the amount of lists added)?  [Example](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test2/index.php)

**CSS related to bottom navigation**

```
<style>
.bottomnavControls {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-right:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #7a7a7a;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}

</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="bottomNav"> 
            <ul class="bottomnavControls left">
           <li style="padding-bottom:5px;"><b>Home</b></li>
           <li><a href=""  class="footer">Login</a></li>
            </ul>    

            <ul class="bottomnavControls left">
           <li style="padding-bottom:5px;"><b>Category</b></li>
           <li><a href=""  class="footer">Games</a></li>
            </ul>

           <ul class="bottomnavControls left">
          <li style="padding-bottom:5px;"><b>About</b></li>
          <li><a href=""  class="footer">Who We Are</a></li>
           </ul>

           <ul class="bottomnavControls left">
             <li style="padding-bottom:5px;"><b>Links</b></li>
             <li><a href="www.google.com" target="_new" class="footer">Google</a></li>
           </ul>

           <ul class="bottomnavControls left">
         <li style="padding-bottom:5px;"><b>Other Stuff</b></li>
             <li><a href=""  class="footer">Stuff</a></li>
          </ul>      
      </div>
</div>
```

**My current Bottom navigation:**

[image]

**My desired outcome:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `float`, you should use [`display: inline-block`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock) here. This way, you can easily center them by putting `text-align: center` on the container.

```css
.bottomNav { text-align: center; }
.bottomnavControls { display: inline-block; }
```

and remove `left` class.

**Note:** `display: inline-block` works fine in modern browsers, but it [needs a hack in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-problem-with-display-inline-block/6545033#6545033).