# HTML <div> placement issues with css

Tags: css, html

Here is the site in question.
http://www.splintercomm.net
I need the divs to site next to each other while remaining spaced apart horizontaly.
In short I dont want them stacked I want them side by side.

```
body {
background-image:url('wild_oliva.png');
} 
div.container   {
overflow: hidden;
}
div.end {
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
background-image:url(stressed_linen.jpg);
border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
margin-bottom:auto
}
div#body {
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
background-image:url(stressed_linen.jpg);
border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
margin-left:20%;
overflow: hidden;
width:80%;
}
div#sidebar {
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
background-image:url(stressed_linen.jpg);
border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;

float:left;
width:18%;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE7 does not understand display: inline-block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-does-not-understand-display-inline-block)

Comment: Not posible diplicate - Just tired

Answer (score 1):

you can make the divs inline using this property:

```
display:inline-block;
```

**Note 1:** You have an error in your doctype declaration

```
<doctype html>
```

Should be

```
<!doctype html>
```

**Note 2:** I only see one div in your sample code.

Comment: I up dated the sites index.html look again if you would :)

Comment: **Note 3** IE7 and lower doesn't support `display:inline-block`

Comment: **Note 3b** You can fix this using the answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-does-not-understand-display-inline-block

Comment: im using the latest firefox to view this

Comment: And the display inline block thing did nothing. Im new to this stuff and dont know what a lot of it does

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what isn't working for you here, as I'm seeing the blocks line up side-by-side in Firefox, chrome and safari. Is this a problem only in IE7?

In any case, I would just float the body div to the left also. Replace the div#body css with the following:

```
div#body {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  background-image:url(stressed_linen.jpg);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:80%;
}
```

Note that the left margin must be less than 2% of the width minus all of the borders (4px), or the body div will be too wide and flow under the sidebar.

Another option is to float the div#body to the right and just omit the left margin:

```
div#body {
  float: right;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  background-image:url(stressed_linen.jpg);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:80%;
}
```

Basically, if you want everything to line up on the same line, the total width of the margins, borders, padding, and box areas must be less than or equal to 100% of the browser (window) width.

18% (sidebar width) + 80% (body width) + 2px (sidebar-borders) + 2px (body-borders)

= 98% + 4px, which is less than 100% at most browser widths.

Comment: Edit your post instead of adding a comment, this is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure if I understand the question, remove `margin:20%;` from `div#body`