# Centering floated images in div

Tags: css, css-float, centering

I'm trying to center floated images on my page, but I can't get it to work. Here is my code

```
.imcontainer {
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}.float {
    float: left;
    font-size: small;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px 7px 0 3px;
    width: auto;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="imcontainer">
    <div class="float"><img width="70px" height="70px" src="image.jpg"></div>
    <div class="float"><img width="70px" height="70px" src="image.jpg"></div>
    <div class="float"><img width="70px" height="70px" src="image.jpg"></div>
    <div class="float"><img width="70px" height="70px" src="image.jpg"></div>
    <div class="float"><img width="70px" height="70px" src="image.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: you're missing almost all `</div>`

Comment: If that's your actual code, take note that the floating divs are all inside each other. Is that by design?

Comment: You have to give fixed width to `float` div first

Comment: Apologies, I did not copy code correctly. Updating now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can center the container and inline-block the children to achieve the desired layout.

```
.imcontainer {
    text-align:center; /* center everything in the container */
}

.float { /* not really float any more so best to rename this */
    display:inline-block; /* so the children on the same line */
    font-size: small;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px 7px 0 3px;
    width: auto;
}
```

I would definitely correct the HTML as well to make it valid

```
<div class="imcontainer">
    <div class="float"><img width="70" height="70" alt="" src="image.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="float"><img width="70" height="70" alt="" src="image.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="float"><img width="70" height="70" alt="" src="image.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="float"><img width="70" height="70" alt="" src="image.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="float"><img width="70" height="70" alt="" src="image.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/NFWPh/ basically same idea.  I would get rid of the space beneath the images.  Feel free to fork and add to your answer. +1

Comment: Thanks, what worked perfectly. One concern is that I've heard display:inline-block is not very widely supported? Is that true?

Comment: Happy to help! If you want to support IE7 and below there are [some workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-does-not-understand-display-inline-block) but every other browser going back a long way [supports it](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block) Click the _Show all versions_ link on that page to see a lot of green = supported :-)

Answer (score 1):

**I think you want like this**

http://jsfiddle.net/JZxxG/

**Your CSS**

```
.imcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%
}
.float {
    float: left;
    font-size: small;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.float {
    float: left;
    font-size: small;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px 7px 0 3px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
.imcontainer {
    text-align: center;
}
.float {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: small;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px 7px 0 3px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@andyb has given a perfect solution, but if you are still not satisfied, you can try by adding `display: table-cell; text-align: center;` to your `float`, not to your `imcontainer`, and if you want some gap, add `padding value`.