# How to create a flexible leader line in div after a label field

Tags: css

```
<div class="titelcontent">
<div class="name">Name</div>
<div class="hzline"></div>
</div>
```

I want `name` div and `hzline` div to auto fit 100% in `titelcontent`.

The label (for example, Name) will vary in length and I want the red underline to span the remainding space of the `titlecontent` div.

How do I achieve the following? It is easy to do this using tables but I can't figure out how to do this via `span` or `div`.

[image: http://s22.postimg.org/zdxtj9da9/Untitled_1.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated to allow background images to show through**

You can make the mark-up a bit tighter by using a pseudo-element as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">Photoshop</div>
</div>
```

and use the following CSS styling:

```
div.wrapper {
    color:#82439a;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: tahoma;
    line-height: 180%;
    background: red url(http://placekitten.com/1000/500) no-repeat left top;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.inner {
    position: relative;
    display: inner;
    color: yellow;
    padding-right: 0.50em;
    border: 1px dotted yellow;
}

div.inner:after {
    content: "\A0";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #d71d00;    
    width: 1000%;
}
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/wE8bC/

**How It Works**

The parent element `div.wrapper` may contain a background image or be transparent and show the background of some ancestor element.  You need to set `overflow: hidden`.

For the label (`<div.inner>`), set `position: relative` and then generate a 100% width pseudo-element with a bottom border to serve as an underline.  Use absolute positioning to place `div.inner:after` to the right of `<div.inner>` (`left: 100%`) and make the width relatively large.  The pseudo-element will trigger an overflow condition but this is taken care of by hiding the overflow in the parent element.  You can control left/right spacing using padding.

You can use set the `display` property to either `inline` or `inline-block`.  If you use `display: inline`, it will work in IE7; adjust the line height as needed for styling.

Note that the generated content is a non-breaking space, hex code "\A0".

**Support for IE7**

If you need to support IE7, you will need a hack if you use `inline-block` as discussed in a previous question: [IE7 does not understand display: inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-does-not-understand-display-inline-block)

IE7 also does not support `table-cell` so some of the other posted solutions will face the same limitation.

Comment: IE7 not support table-cell ture.. your one nice solution but i can't use div.inner background color. my page body have background. and the line i need to 100% width that would be background image. ...  your current code not work me, which i am looking for.. can u try for me with background image as line and without background color inner.. thanks u so much

Comment: @AccoreLTD I was able to modify the CSS to allow the background to show through.  Please check the updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: @March ... cool man... actual what i wanted... see this..http://jsfiddle.net/wE8bC/7/  your code also work ... and support IE7 .. right ?

Comment: @AccoreLTD In your fiddle, multiple lines, increase the width of the pseudo-element, say 4000% or 3000px, so that the element fills up the width of the root element.  I assume you will replace it with an image of line segment (use repeat-x).

Comment: @AccoreLTD The code will work if you use display: inline for the pseudo-element, so the code will work in IE7 without a hack.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `div` like a `table` by using `table-cell`.

```css
.titlecontent {
    display: table;
}
.name {
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.hzline {
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AjwVD/2/).

Comment: thanks all guys.. i will try and see which one work for me.. but i will use background image.. not border line.. so will see which one will work.. thanks again.. i will report here.

Comment: this one work pefrectly .. just not support IE7 .. but i don't much care IE7 now :) thanks man...

Answer (score 0):

Or an alternative to using `display: table`:

```
.name {
    float: left;
}
.line-wrapper {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
.hzline {
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JdQ7c/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I've guessed you are looking something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/cL6Sd/1/). Please find my solution based on my understanding about the image you posted.

HTML

```
<div>
    <span>Photoshop</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>Adobe Illustrator</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>3D Max</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>Maya</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>Windows 8 Pro</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    line-height: 150%;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #d71d00;
}

div span{
    position:relative;
    bottom: -10px;
    background:#fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
    color:#82439a;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: tahoma;
}
```

Please do let me know your feedback. Thanks

Comment: . my page body have background. and the line i need to 100% width that would be background image. ... your current code not work me, which i am looking for.. can u try for me with background image as line and without background color inner.. thanks u so much

Comment: Cool. You possibly have got a solution. Thanks for the feedback. Cheers!