# Why the page displays differently in IE8 and in chm (CSS "display: inline-block" issue)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, chm

On a Windows 7 with IE8, I find `display: inline-block` works quite well. However, after I compile the html file into chm, the page inside chm does not display well, as if `inline-block` does not take any effect.

Is there a way to have chm display the same as in IE8? Thank you.

[image]

My html source is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>title to fill</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
#topcanvas {
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0; 
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}

#chjnavi {
    font-size: 10pt;
    background-color: #eee;

    padding: 0em 1em;
    list-style-type: none;  
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

#chjnavi ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#chjnavi li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
        /* !!! */

    cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
</head>

<div id="topcanvas">
<div id="chjnavi">
    <ul id="navibar_topul">
        <li id="gentoc-t">item 1</li>
        <li id="codecolor-t">item 2</li>
        <li id="linenum-t">item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<p> My text. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the answer finally. [A post at west-wind.com](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Feb/15/Make-your-CHM-Help-Files-show-HTML5-and-CSS3-content) tells me that I need to do a registry hack to have CHM reader(hh.exe) use IE8 rendering mode, otherwise, hh.exe uses at most IE7.

The registry hack is: Save the following code to a .reg file, then double click to import into registry.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"hh.exe"=dword:00001f40
```

OK. At least there is a solution for IE8 M$ system.

This question is related to [Will the IE9 WebBrowser Control Support all of IE9's features, including SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control)

Comment: Word of warning with this hack: The change is global, meaning all CHM content will show up using the updated IE version. This may cause problems for other (older) help files that expect IE 7 to be used. Personally I've not had any issues, but it's good to keep that in mind before you change a global setting on people's machines.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Inline-block you with have to use  float:left; for IE8 as it doesn't support the property of Inline-block;

So this is what you will have to add to your code.

```
#chjnavi li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    float:left\9; /* This works for IE8 and below  so apply this to your code*/
}
```

Comment: What does \9 in "left\9" mean, please?

Comment: And your code is still using ``inline-block``, contrary to your opinion of "instead of inline-block".

Comment: \9 is a hack used for IE. This line of code is added after your css this will only apply to IE and will not affect other browsers.

Inline-block being in the code doesn't matter as that will apply to other browser as anyways Inline-block will not work for in IE.

Comment: Just in case somebody ever needs this, the correct answer is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-does-not-understand-display-inline-block This answer breaks the view pretty badly in my case...