# List style CSS not being honoured in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, slider, html-lists

I am trying to resolve an issue with an image slider in IE9.

Please see http://betelec2.placeneuve.com/index.html

The same page is rendered using php at http://betelec2.placeneuve.com/index.php and it works fine, but the load time is slow, so the home page has been "recreated" using static content with the .html file extension.

The site is htpassword protected and the username and password are placeneuve and patali123 respectively.

The issue I am having is that in IE9, the slider is disregarding the list styles. It is displaying the images stacked one above the other (rather than in a row with overflow hidden) and it is using default unordered list styles (with bullets). Furthermore, it is ignoring the positioning of the text overlay. Finally, it is doing the same thing to the image thumbnails that appear below the slider.

If you look at the site in Chrome, FF or Safari, it works without a glitch.

IE9's developer tools are not very useful, at least for me, and I am a bit lost as to how to resolve this.

Unfortunately, I received this site from someone else who had concatenated and minified the CSS and didn't provide the original CSS, so finding the selectors is pain as well. However, the relevant CSS selectors start with `.rg-ss-`

Anyone able to assist would be most appreciated.

Comment: Please read this first: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following:

```
.fatfooter2 ul li {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: inline;  /* display inline should put your list items in line *\
}
```

Comment: that selector is unrelated to the issue I am having...I am referring to the image slider at the top, and the parent class starts with `.rg-ss-` Anyway, I added the styles you suggested and it makes no difference.

Comment: I see it perfectly fine in IE9.

Comment: are you accessing it at http://betelec2.placeneuve.com/index.html or http://betelec2.placeneuve.com/index.php?

Comment: well, now it is working...I am not sure why...but I don't think it is a cache issue as I deleted cache between each load and have it disabled anyway. With IE, I find it is hit-and-miss as to why it does things. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's always hard to make IE happy. It is very demanding and attention seeking piece of software.

Comment: More like it is a very stubborn software that thinks it knows better and tries to pigeonhole developers into doing things its way, damned be standards!!!

Comment: Hmmm...damned IE7...it is still doing the same thing on Vista. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Not sure if it was display issue. But if it was then try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-does-not-understand-display-inline-block

Comment: nope, unless it is a cache thing that IE7 doesn't clear caches even when clearing caches, the suggestion on that page doesn't make a difference. :(...life with IE is the opposite of a box of chocolates!!!