# How to place this tab in horizontal in IE 7?

Tags: css

The image is the menu list items which displays vertically in IE7 but I want to display it horizontally. I am using smart wizard plugins (framestyle.css) which displays perfectly in all other browsers except IE7.

[image]

**framestyle.css**: this is the css for smart wizard plugins.

```
.swMain ul.anchor {
 position:fixed;
  z-index:1099;
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;  
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.swMain ul.anchor li{ 
  position: relative; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  padding-top:3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  clear:both;
  display:inline;
  float: none;  
}

.swMain ul.anchor li a {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:3px;
  height:35px;
  width:146px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline-style:none;
}
```

**IE7.css**: this is the css for the menu list item for IE7 browser

```
.swMain ul.anchor {  
display:inline;
position:relative; 
list-style: none;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
zoom:1;
float:left;
clear:both;
}

.swMain ul.anchor li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: -10px; 
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  clear:both;
  display:inline;
  float:left;   

}
.swMain ul.anchor li a {
  display:block;
  position:relative; 
   float:left;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline-style:none;
}
```

Comment: Can you create example via JSFiddle or JSbin pleas?

Comment: wow, there are still crazy people out there supporting a browser with less than 1% marketshare.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to display inline horizontally, you shouldn't have `clear: both;` in the first place, because that will put the floating items on a new line.

You should also remove the `float: left;` from `.swMain ul.anchor li` in your IE7 stylesheet.

For clarity, the following code will put your list-items inline horizontally:

```
li {
display:inline;
}
```

If you want to style the list-items with some padding and other fancy stuff, you can try `inline-block`, but this will cause a few issues with IE7. You will find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-does-not-understand-display-inline-block).

By the way, I was required to support IE7 for some specific purpose projects, but in general you may very well drop IE7 support altogether.

Hope this helps.