# css : prevent div width from expanding to available width

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

How can I prevent div from expanding? I want div with elements not to take 100% of available space and have width that it's children have. I need this for centering parent div horizontally. The trick is that child elements should share float:left or diplay: inline-block and fluid width, so there can be few rows of child elements.

I can not wrap each row in its own div since it will break responsive design.

Comment: There's several possibilities: `display:inline-block` is good for this (be aware of the [IE7 hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6545033/870729))

Comment: Set `display: inline-block` to the parent and wrap it by a container has `text-align: center;`

Comment: As this seems like a trivial problem, it might help to show your HTML so we can see what challenge you're facing.

Comment: Setting display:inline block doesn't prevent element from expanding if there are more than one row of child elements

Comment: have you trying setting a static width as well as a max-width?

Comment: Nowadays there's `width: fit-content`.

Answer (score 18):

You should use `display: table;` It will shrink to the size of it's contents and can also be centered and positioning without having to assign a given width.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/9VRzM/

Comment: try setting float:left or display: inline-block to child elements, it will cause problems

Comment: @vlad I actually tried setting `float:left` and `display: inline-block` and I don't see a problem.  In these situations, the parent container will expand as much as it can to allow the child elements to fill the available width.  You can constrain the width using the maximum-width property for the parent container.

Comment: still expands when more text

Answer (score 18):

You can set the width property of the children to `fit-content`. Doing so will make these elements take up only as much horizontal space as they need and is available within the parent.

You can also set width to `max-content` but this will ignore the width of the parent and content will extend as far as any descendants need and possibly overflow the parent.

**Example**:

Problem setup:

```css
.parent {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Content for child
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution:

```css
.parent {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.child {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Content for child
  </div>
</div>
```

Support for `fit-content` is pretty good ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=width%20fit-content)?). There's support for `fit-content` on pretty much all the major desktop browsers (except IE), and unknown support on some of the mobile browsers.

Answer (score 3):

If you truly want the parent `div` to collapse around its child elements (for whatever reason, based on what you're trying to accomplish) and you then want to center that `div`, then @Vector's answer is spot on, use `display: table` with `margin: 0 auto`.

If it's ok for the `div` to remain expanded to the full width of the container in which you're trying to center your children, then you have at least a couple more options, again depending on your particular situation.

You can use `text-align: center`.

```css
.content {
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
}

.content span {
  display: inline;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>
```

You could also use the newer `display: flex` with `justify-content: center`, depending on the level of browser compatibility you're supporting, of course.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
}

.content div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you modify DOM adding extra html elements inside a div and that cause it to be expanded, a simple solution would be to add that css to the root element of those extra html elements:

> max-width: fit-content;

That will prevent them to expand the parent div's width.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using `display: inline-block`?  DIV will take up 100% width because they are block elements.

Comment: This will collapse the div but it won't be (easily) centered.