# How to properly line up a dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, nav

This is my first time doing a dropdown menu. I'm confused as to why my dropdown menu is acting strange. I simply wanted to hide the sub menus such that when it is hovered, it will show.

The problem is that when it is hovered, it breaks the nav in half. I don't get it. 
Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wEwQ/) demonstrating it, and here's my HTML & CSS nav code:

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a style="background-color:#000000;color:#FFFE41;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="history.html">Camera Phone</a></li>
    <li><a href="focus.html">Manual & Auto Focus</a></li>
    <li><a href="exposure.html">Exposure</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="iso.html">ISO</a></li>
            <li><a href="aperture.html">Aperture</a></li>
            <li><a href="shutterspeed.html">Shutter Speed</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="whitebalance.html">White Balance</a></li>
    <li><a href="lowlight.html">Low Light</a></li>
    <li><a href="epilogue.html">Epilogue</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul#nav {
    margin-top: -9px;
    /*put nav in the upper-top browser*/
    list-style-type: none;
    /*gets rid of bullets*/
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav li {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    /*display list horizontally*/
    margin-left: -4px;
    /*dense the links together*/
}
#nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    /*don't break onto new lines and follow padding accordingly*/
    padding:10px;
    /*give space between links*/
    border-top:1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
}
#nav li > ul {
    display:none;
    /*hide the sub-nav menus*/
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
    /*display sub menus when hovered over*/
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:10%;
    left:61%;
    /*pushes the nav right under where the menu is*/
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your html looks pretty good (except the inline styles - avoid them where possible!)

The solution to getting a dropdown nav to work is surprisingly simple, once you've done it enough times.

First, your parent li's need to be `position: relative`:

```
#nav li{
    margin: 0;
    display: inline; /*display list horizontally*/
    margin-left: -4px; /*dense the links together*/
    position: relative;
}
```

Then, your child nav needs to be `position: absolute`, and your top / left need to be positioned within the parent li.  By the way, I recommend styling everything except the "Reveal" on the base element, then just styling the "reveal" on the hover:

```
#nav li > ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width: 200px; /* Adjust as needed.  10% is now 10% of the parent li, so not enough */
    height: auto;
    left: -999em; /* this hides the menu when not hovered */
    top: 40px; /* adjust to match the height of the parent li */
}

#nav li:hover > ul{
   left: 0; /* show the menu when hovered */
}
```

Finally, when it comes to navigation, I'm a fan of using `display:inline-block` rather than inline for the nav elements, so that you can properly apply padding, etc.  If you do so, remember to use the [IE7 hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6545033/870729) (if you intend to support IE7).

Comment: top: 100%; will, I believe automatically position the menu directly below the parent.

Comment: @Paulie_D - interesting - never tried it.  I personally like the absolute control I get with pixel measurements on things like this.

Comment: True but if you change one height you have to change the other which is a pain...unless you're using a variable in LESS or SASS.