# How to debug webpages for IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, responsive-design

My webpages looks awful in IE7 but there's no way I can inspect elements in it, right?
How can I debug my webpages for IE7?

Comment: If you are looking for potential issues, I would first look at the use of inline-block, where IE7 needs a workaround. See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-does-not-understand-display-inline-block

Comment: @HenrikHelmers I ran into this problem before and it's such an annoying thing that some styles are not supported in IE. I used to write `background:url` which is not supported either...

Answer (score 1):

Press F12 (shortcut), a developer tools will be opened. or go tools> Developer tools, you can inspect, css, html so on. Try this

Comment: well,the problem is that the developer tool in IE7 is too weak while IE7 often has compatibility problems with CSS styles, this makes debugging even more difficult.