# What's the difference between inline-block and appending a <div class="clear"></div>?

Tags: css, html

I want to put several divs into a container div, and line them up to make the container look like it has columns inside.

```
<div>
    <div id="col_1"></div>
    <div id="col_2"></div>
</div>
```

I can choose those divs to be `inline-block` or make them `float:left` with specific width and append a empty div to the last which the css style is `clear:both`.

Both seem fine, but which way should I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicat [float:left; vs display:inline; vs display:inline-block; vs display:table-cell;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell)

Answer (score 0):

In a word, **if your page needs to run on old browser** (less than IE8), consider the `float` method.

**If you have no matter with this**, then use display: inline-block (or any of the other new display properties). It's cleaner (as you don't need an HTML element to restore the float) and simpler.

Comment: * less than IE 8, not including IE 8 (on which it works)

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "less than IE8"

Comment: Just wanted to make that clear because I got confused for a second there

Comment: It can work in IE6/IE7 if you [use hacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6545033/1763929).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use those hacks. It works now, but what if a new version of IE (or any other browsers) interprete that hack ?

Comment: Or maybe if you set these hacks in lt-ie8 conditionnal comment, so it won't be interpreted by another browser.

Comment: The hack is safe to use (if not using less), I don't know why @enguerranws recommended not to use them. An one more thing `*` targets only IE7, so `*display: inline;` it's taken only from IE7 and nothing else, so there is no problem using them in the css. For the IE6 it's the `_` `_display:inline;`. Just to clear the confusion.

Comment: How do you know this syntax (*property) won't be used in a near futur ? That's why we call that a hack, it's dirty and not futur-proof.

Comment: Because there are standards, and we should follow them...You can say the same thing for every css property, we don't know if it will be there after 3-5 years, so we shouldn't use them? I think there are enough special characters, that can be implemented in the css so it won't overwrite this one. If that is you interpretation of a hack ok.

Comment: '*property' or '_property' are standards ? :D Yeah, follow standards, not hacks. If you follow standards, your site will live long, if you follow hacks, your site can break tomorrow.

Comment: Nope I mean there standards, and there is now way in the standards to overwrite something...You are saying like one day the font-size wont be for the font-size, but for something else, give me one example of something that was overwritten from older css version and I will take my words back. Since `unsafe` is invalid comment in this case.

Comment: I just say those hacks are absolutely non-standards, and that's why we shouldn't use them. I made websites in 2000 with non standard code, hacks, as everyone, it's all broken. Feel free to use hacks.

Comment: Basically, right now W3C is working on variables, new selectors, and lot of things. What if they use '*property' syntax ? As it's not a standard use, they could easily consider it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a personal choice.

When using float you must clear them, so like you said you can add a clearing div or make the container with `overflow: auto;`.

When using `inline-block` you should have in mind you should add `font-size: 0` to the parent div to remove the spacing between the divs and add the default font-size to the divs. (there is the negative margin fix, but I don't personally like it)

If you want the col1 to be in the left and col2 to be at right, better use floats (left/right).

If you want the cols to be verticaly aligned in the middle/bottom, better use `inline-block`.

But for most other cases is personal choice.