# Make two divs appear aside each other fails even when it shouldn't

Tags: css

I'm trying to make two div's appear aside each other, but it just isn't working.

I'm trying to create a search bar and button that look joined together. I'm almost there, except that my button appears below, and not inline with the div.

Shouldn't this work? Where am I going wrong, and how do I get this right?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Search Bar</title>
<style>

input {
    border: none;
    height: 18px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

button {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 39, 59, 0.2);
    margin: 0;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 0;
    width:100px;
}

.outer {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}

.inner {
    width: 395px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right:none;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="button"><button>Search</button></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change css as

```
.inner {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: #CCCCCC -moz-use-text-color #CCCCCC #CCCCCC;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid none solid solid;
    border-width: 1px medium 1px 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 395px;
}
input {
    border: medium none;
    height: 18px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 380px;
}
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

button {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 39, 59, 0.2);
    height: 28px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Hope this will work fine for you....

Comment: This works good across all browsers, except when I add the .outer container, the space below isn't equal to the space top, left and right. Know what might me causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: for outer class
.outer {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
}

Is it not working.
write what you are using...

Comment: Please see the image I uploaded. I'm using you same code, except with changes to the colors. See the bottom, it has extra padding.

Comment: Add display: -moz-box; for Firefox browser.
I'm searching for other browsers...
And decrease the padding to 4px

Answer (score 0):

add

```
display:inline-block;
```

to .inner

http://jsfiddle.net/MrdHc/

Answer (score 0):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/CD3kS/

setting `display:inline-block` will get you there.

now there are a few interesting things with elements that are inline-block

they get default [letter spacing](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) around them which is normally 4px

they need a `display:inline;zoom:1;` hack to work in [ie7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-does-not-understand-display-inline-block)

updated css bits:

```
.outer {
    ...
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.inner {
    ...
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
    /*float: right*/
    margin-left:-4px;
}

.button button { height:30px; }
```