# How can I display two div in one line via css inline property

Tags: css, inline

I try to use css inline property to make div node display in one line, below is my code

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   .inline { 
    display: inline; 
    border: 1px solid red; 
    margin:10px;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <div class='inline'><div>I'm here</div></div>
   <div class='inline'><div>I'm follow</div></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The result is not right, the two div with class 'inline' still display in two line, and the border is display incorrect too.
I don't know what happen, who can help me?

thanks

Comment: What about reading up a bit on what `inline` does?

Comment: in this case you can probably fix it by just removing the extra <div> in each line, demo: https://codepen.io/lznt/pen/PowmLgX

Comment: If there is not enough space, inline-block will not work, in that case use white-space: nowrap.

Answer (score 33):

use `inline-block` instead of `inline`. [Read more information here about the difference between inline and inline-block.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)

```
.inline { 
display: inline-block; 
border: 1px solid red; 
margin:10px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SdzG6/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but there is too many space between two div with inline-block

Comment: that because of you have given margin. Remove margin it will come next to each.

Comment: This solution has one annoying issue: since `div`s are made `inline` you have to keep no spaces, new lines etc between them in your HTML. Otherwise, browsers will render a space between them. See this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/1n2a05ob/): you can't manage to keep both `div`s on the same line unless you put theirs tags without anything in between.

Comment: It's working well in laptop but not in small screens like iphones

Comment: This solution doesn't work when content inside an inline div overflows (e.g. big tests)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use `display:inline` to achieve this:

```
.inline { 
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;/*Add float left*/
    margin :10px;
}
```

You can use `float-left`.

> Using float:left is best way to place multiple div elements in one
>   line. Why? Because inline-block does have some problem when is viewed
>   in IE older versions.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r4ES6/3/)

Comment: Probably i'm wrong about IE9. Only IE8 and newer have full support for display: inline-block. IE7 and older apply it to elements that are inline by default (like span) and not to any other elements (like li or div).

Comment: IE6 and IE7 (if someone still cares about these) only need a [simple CSS hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-does-not-understand-display-inline-block/6545033#6545033) and you're fine. Floating brings along a nice set of hard-to-understand problems that make it necessary to dive into clearing techniques and other strange stuff (for a beginner, at least). And that's in every browser.

Comment: @kapa: See my comment under the `inline-block` answer on when the `float` solution might be preferrable than `inline-block` one.