# Why does IE7 specific script destroys appearance of webpage in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

IE7 did show my navbar horizontally instead of vertically. Searching the web I found an excellent solution on stackoverflow: [IE7 does not understand display: inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-does-not-understand-display-inline-block/6545033#6545033)
Everything worked fine with IE7 - navbar appeared horizontally - but with addition of the IE7 script appearance of IE8 is completely abolished (blank page) - if I remove the script IE8 is working fine again.

So this is the script I add to the head section:

```
<!–-[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie7.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]–->
```

and this the corresponding stylesheet:

**ie7.css:**

```
nav ul li {
     display: inline-block; 
     *display: inline;
     zoom: 1; 
   }
```

the stylesheet for the nav

**main.css:**

```
nav {
    font-family:'freestyle script', sans serif;
    font-weight:1000;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align:left;
    display:block;

}
nav ul {
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -15px;
}
nav ul li {
    float: inside;
    display: inline-block; 
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 23px;
    padding: 0px 23px 0px 0px;
}
```

What is the explanation for this unexpected problem with IE8. And is there a solution to get IE8 working again.

Comment: Have a look here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic html5 element `<nav>` is not supported by IE before Version 9. You can try to use modernizr for a polyfill. When you have to support old browsers, you may change the `<nav>` with something like `<div id="navigation"></div>` and alter your css according to this new structure. You may just ran into some silly problems with the compatibility mode

Comment: Make sure IE8 doesnt open your page in compatibility mode.

Comment: @Nico O. Modernizer did not help. I finally got it working in both IE7 and IE8 when putting the IE7 script not in the head section, but at the end of the body section !?! Anybody with an explanation ?