# div layout with float: left

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How can I make this html structure

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
```

be displayed like this while div#1 and #2 have css float:left
[image: div layout]

( id names are integers only for demonstration purposes )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the given HTML structure, here's two different methods. One is working around the floats, the other is simply using absolute or relative positioning to force the third div into place.

HTML

```
<div id="d1">One</div>
<div id="d2">Two</div>
<div id="d3">Three</div>
```

CSS using inline-block ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cn146z6r/1/)):

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#d1 {
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
}
#d2 {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.3);
}
#d3 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

CSS using relative positioning ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ga5oLak/1/)):

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#d1 {
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
}
#d2 {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.3);
}
#d3 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    left: 220px;
    top: -430px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. in my case the content of div three is dynamic so I decided to go with the display: inline-block variant. anyone who´s reading this keep in mind to apply the ie7 hack to inline-block elements [ie7 hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-does-not-understand-display-inline-block)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you will need to change the `id`'s of your `<div>`'s to start with an alphabet rather than just one single digit since you won't be able to style your `<div>`'s using CSS then. Moreover, to achieve the sort of a layout which you're trying to create, you will need to wrap your two floated `<div>`'s inside a `<div>` and set the `display` property of that `<div>` to `inline-block`.

Here's a demo:

```css
#one,
#two {
  float: left;
}
#one {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
#two {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
#three {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
#one {
  background: pink;
}
#two {
  background: brown;
}
#three {
  background: gray;
}
div#row-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}
div#row-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="row-left">
  <div id="one">One</div>
  <div id="two">Two</div>
</div>
<div id="row-right">
  <div id="three">Three</div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** If you want to align the three boxes to the right side of the page then you will need to wrap your HTML inside another `<div>` and set the `text-align` property of that `<div>` to right, like this:

```css
#wrapper {
  text-align: right;
}
#one,
#two {
  float: left;
}
#one {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
#two {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
#three {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
#one {
  background: pink;
}
#two {
  background: brown;
}
#three {
  background: gray;
}
div#row-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}
div#row-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="row-left">
    <div id="one">One</div>
    <div id="two">Two</div>
  </div>
  <div id="row-right">
    <div id="three">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. "How can I make this html structure... be displayed like this..."

Comment: @blexen It isn't mentioned anywhere that the structure cannot be modified.

Comment: The part I quoted seems pretty clear, otherwise it's asking a completely different question.

Comment: @blexen A completely different question? Please explain me how my answer doesn't achieve what the OP has requested.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed here - http://jsfiddle.net/3147og96/1/
html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="one">1</div>
<div id="two">2</div>
<div id="three">3</div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.parent {
    height: auto;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 110px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.parent div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}

#one, #two {

    float: left;
}
```

Comment: You do know that the following styles (`#1, #2 { float: left; }`) don't get applied, right?

Comment: This appears to put div 3 in the bottom left, and div 2 in the top-right, instead of the other way around.